# Running a script for it's subdirectories

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to run a screenshot making script, but i wan't it to run in it's subdirectories.

I'm having let's say a map called moviemap, there are 3 maps inside with 5 movies in each map.
I want to go inside the map moviemap, and than run a script where it will start making screenshots of all the movies inside the 3 maps.

How can i do that?

I currently have this but it doesn't work :(

```
#!/bin/bash
basedir=$1

for dir in "$basedir"/* 
do
      for i in *;
      do
           vcs -n40 -c4 -H 267 -a 400/267 -U0 $i
      done
done
```

Comment: What is a map here? Is it an image? If it is, how do you go inside that image?

Comment: Does your `vcs ...` command work outside of the loop, if you replace $i with a moviefile?

Comment: a map is a folder. Lets say movies.january and let's say there are 10 maps, all with dates, example 01.01, 05.01, 08.01, 10.01, etc...
In all those date maps there are movies inside. I just want to run vcs from the dir movies.january instead of browsing to each date folder. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok if your setup is like this:

```
Movies/Jan/movie1.mp4
Movies/Jan/movie2.mp4
Movies/Feb/movie3.mp4
Movies/Feb/movie4.mp4
Movies/march/movie5.mp4
```

Where Movies is your basedir. Then the following script will list all your movie files with full paths relative to the basedir.

```
for dir in $basedir/*/*
do
  for file in $dir/
  do
    echo $file
  done
done
```

Replace `echo $file` with your vcs command but try it like this first to make sure your getting the correct files.

This has no fault tolerance and will not recurse into sub directories. You might want to add a check that only video files are grabbed.